# libxlsxwriter with MinGW

Tags: c++, c, mingw, libxlsxwriter

For two days I have spent several hours trying to get libxlsxwriter to work with mingw on Windows. I followed the instructions to install and build the library, but every time I attempt to include the header files in one of my projects and use one of the function in the library, I end up getting the same error:

```
D:\Apps\CLion\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\Simon\CLionProjects\myexcel\cmake-build-debug --target all -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable myexcel.exe
D:/Apps/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\myexcel.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): in function `main':
C:/Users/Simon/CLionProjects/myexcel/main.cpp:4: undefined reference to `workbook_new'
D:/Apps/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Simon/CLionProjects/myexcel/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `workbook_add_worksheet'
D:/Apps/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Simon/CLionProjects/myexcel/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `worksheet_write_string'
D:/Apps/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/Simon/CLionProjects/myexcel/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `workbook_close'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\myexcel.dir\build.make:85: myexcel.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/myexcel.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:83: all] Error 2
```

My code is very basic (it's pretty much one of the sample codes provided):

```
#include "xlsxwriter.h"

int main() {
    lxw_workbook  *workbook  = workbook_new("myexcel.xlsx");
    lxw_worksheet *worksheet = workbook_add_worksheet(workbook, NULL);
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    worksheet_write_string(worksheet, row, col, "Hello me!", NULL);
    return workbook_close(workbook);
}
```

I have tried several ways to get deploy mingw, but I've ultimately settled for msys2 as a platform to host mingw as I feel the *nix environments are beneficial when it comes to managing a multitude of packages and it comes with the needed zlib preinstalled.

For all it'S worth here's my toolchain configuration in CLion 2019.3

[image]

and here's my project configuration:

[image]

Any ideas what's wrong here? I am a newby as it relates to C/C++... help is very much appreciated!

---

EDIT:

I've tried to install the built files from the mys2 console with pacman pacman -Ss xlsx. From what it looks like, it's already installed. This is the output of the console:

```
$ pacman -Ss xlsx
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-libxlsxwriter 0.9.4-1
    A C library for creating Excel XLSX files (mingw-w64)
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-python-openpyxl 3.0.2-1
    A python library to read/write Excel 2007 xlsx/xlsm file (mingw-w64)
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-python-xlsxwriter 1.2.7-1
    A Python module for creating Excel XLSL files (mingw-w64)
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-xlnt 1.4.0-1
    User-friendly xlsx library for C++14 (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-libxlsxwriter 0.9.4-1
    A C library for creating Excel XLSX files (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python-openpyxl 3.0.2-1
    A python library to read/write Excel 2007 xlsx/xlsm file (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-python-xlsxwriter 1.2.7-1
    A Python module for creating Excel XLSL files (mingw-w64)
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-xlnt 1.4.0-1
    User-friendly xlsx library for C++14 (mingw-w64)
```

I don't get it, frankly. There is no libxlsxwriter.so anywhere. I have the two files (libxlsxwriter.a, libxlsxwriter.dll) in the usr/local folder and in the home folder (where they have been built originally).

Comment: I don't know about your IDE but it seems you aren't building the xlsxwriter library

Comment: MSYS2 includes libxlsxwriter as a package (`pacman -Ss xlsx`) so you could install that rather than trying to build it

Comment: Seems you are right. I've got these two files built: libxlsxwriter.a, libxlsxwriter.dll No signs of a libxlsxwriter.so, which should be there, according to the manual. Is this correct? I will try your suggested solution and report back

Comment: I atttempted you solution and edited my post. Still nothing, unfortunately

Comment: There are no `.so` files in Windows. You should link against the `.a` file

Comment: Did you  set up your project to *link* with `libxlsxwriter.a`?

Comment: Could you tell me exactly how this linking is done? I would love to try that one out. I thought I merely had to include the header file(s) (`#include "xlsxwriter.h"`) in the .cpp file.

Comment: maybe check CLion or cmake documentation for how to link against a library

Comment: .so is a dynamic library used on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the libxlsxwriter library as Msys2 package and install them using (from MinGW 64 shell) the following command: 
`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libxlsxwriter`